# How to group in MySQL a column with multiple choices under only one of them?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table in which a certain column's data is **sometimes** missing, in which cases has just a dash.

But since there's another column which is unique, the missing data can be deduced from other rows.

In other words, I have something like this:

| Unique model | Maker | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd1234 | - | 56 |
| zgh675 | Company Y | 40 |
| abcd1234 | Company X | 3 |
| zgh675 | - | 10 |
| abcd1234 | Company X | 1 |

Which query can I use to automatically reach the following (the list of Makers is dynamic but every model can only go to one of them):

| Unique model | Maker | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd1234 | Company X | 60 |
| zgh675 | Company Y | 50 |

?

Comment: Not only does the question have reproducible code, @Strawberry, but someone already used it to answer it successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may aggregate by unique model and then take the `MAX` value of the maker, along with the sum of the profit:

```sql
SELECT model, MAX(maker) AS maker, SUM(profit) AS profit
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY model;
```

This approach should work assuming that each model only has one unique non `NULL` value.